# Adding connection to SQL Server : Can't select a database name

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, datasource

I can't select or enter a database name in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012:

1. In the Server Explorer tab, I add a connection
2. Select Microsoft SQL Server as a data source
3. I'm able to detect my server name (SQL Server 2008) and the connection test is working (I tested in SQL Server Management Studio, and I can access the database)
4. I can't select any database in the dropbox. Even if I write up the name, it's not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you type the name, what does "not working" mean?

Comment: Unable to find the requested .net framework data provider. it may not be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the folder C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config (should see for other versions as well), open the file machine.config and then see if the  tag was duplicated. If it's duplicated then, delete the duplicated tag in all machine.config of all .net versions.

Comment: Which "tag" do you mean?

Comment: If I recall, it was the DbProviderFactories tag